# How does the join() method of Thread class work?

Tags: java

Consider the following code :

```
class ThreadJoinTest{
    public static void main(String[] arguments){
        TimeUnit unit; 
        final Thread taskThread = new Thread(task);
        taskThread.start();
        taskThread.join(unit.millis(timeout));   
     }
}
```

So when the main thread would execute the line `taskThread.join()` with a time out value, the main thread is giving the `taskThread` ample time to finish its task? Is this the main objective of the join method?

What will happen if:

1. `taskThread` finishes its execution before the time out period?
2. What happens if the timeout is reached but the `taskThread` has not finished executing? Does the `taskThread` get a chance to finish its task or not?
3. How does the main thread know that join returned because the `taskThread` finished normally or because timeout was reached?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `main` will be allowed to start again as soon as `taskThread` is
   done.
2. Then `main` will be allowed to start again, and `taskThread` will continue. Both threads will be allowed to finish.
3. If either the `taskThread` finished normally or the timeout is reached main will continue to execute. There is no way for `main` to know if the timeout occurred or if `taskThread` finished executing without using some other means of communication.

Comment: I think your answer answers the first two questions but not the third . Since the return from join is of type void how do the main thread know if the Thread taskThread completeted normally or because of the timeout ?

Comment: so is this a flaw in the design ..what do you think ?

Comment: Well, it would have been nice if `join()` returned some kind of status, but I guess they just figured there are other ways to solve that if you really need to know.

Comment: I can think of other ways like updating global data structure by the taskThread after it finishes. So the main thread can know the status just by polling that global data structure ....but it would have been nice if they(the java designers) provided a return on join  instead.

Comment: You could just check `isAlive()` if you want to know if `taskThread` has finished or not.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Sounds like a good alternative. It won't prove if the timeout occurred or not, but that is probably irrelevant.

Comment: True, but if you just check after returning from the timed join, and it returns `true`, then you do know that the timeout occurred.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel +1 for suggesting isAlive()

Answer (score 4):

`join()` when called on the thread, **will wait for that thread to die** (ie for the run method of that thread to get done with..). Only then the line below the `join()` will execute. **But giving a timeout within join(), will make the join() effect to be nullified after the specific timeout.**

Though the timeout occurs, the taskThread will be allowed to finish the work.

Comment: so assuming that timeout happens and taskThread isn't done yet , does taskThread die because of the timeout ?

Comment: No, the even after the timeout occurs, the taskhTread will be allowed to finish its work

Comment: ok got it . What about the last question ? Please also see my comment on Keppil's answer .

Comment: As for the last question, consider using Future.get()

Answer (score 1):

The timeout condition will take precedence. When the timeout is reached, the main thread and taskThread are equally probable candidates to execute.